# Add/update user_meta on change of role

Tags: php, wordpress, hook, user-roles

I'm trying to save the current date as user meta when the role of a user is changed. I'm having no joy with this code but can't see where I am going wrong. Any pointers much appreciated!

```
function user_role_update( $user_id, $new_role ) {
    add_user_meta( $user_id, 'roleupdated', current_time( 'mysql' ) 
);
}

add_action( 'set_user_role', 'user_role_update', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: how do you know the data is not being saved? Are you displaying it elsewhere, are you looking directly at the DB?

Comment: I'm looking directly in the database!

Comment: Great! Second, where is the code you posted located, functions.php?

Comment: Thanks for your time Max but I've managed to solve the issue! I'm using Justin Tadlock's Members plugin and it doesn't use the set_user_role hook. Managed to find the exact same problem in the plugin's support forum. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/action-hook-when-role-changes/

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue was that Justin Tadlock's Members plugin does not use the 'set_user_role' hook but you can use the 'add_user_role' or 'remove_user_role' hooks instead (depending on your needs). I changed my code to 'add_user_role' as this sufficed for my needs and it's now working.

```
function user_role_update( $user_id, $role ) {
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'roleupdated', current_time( 'mysql' ) );
}

add_action( 'add_user_role', 'user_role_update', 10, 2 );
```